# MapReduce WordCount example provides two mappers v2.5.1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When I go through the Hadoop MapReduce tutorial, [at one point](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Walk-through) it has mentioned following,

> For the given sample input the first map emits:  < Hello, 1>  < World,
>   1>  < Bye, 1>  < World, 1>
>
> The second map emits:  < Hello, 1>  < Hadoop, 1>  < Goodbye, 1>  <
>   Hadoop, 1>

How can we be sure that the first input file will be processed by one mapper and the second one by another? Or is it just an assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
One mapper cannot process more than one file. So, for two files we need at least two mappers.

**Longer (but still simplified) answer:**
One mapper processes exactly one input split. One file creates at least one input split. So, two files, create at least two input splits and hence are processed by two mappers.

A file can be partitioned to more splits, if, for example, it is larger than the size of a block. The default size of a block is (in the current version) 128MB (it was 64MB in the previous versions). If a file is larger than 128MB, then it produces more than one input split. So, even the same file can be processed by two or more mappers. This is determined by the InputFormat (read [this post](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces), too).

**[Detailed answer](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#closer)**